# How to use camel recipentList

Tags: apache-camel

I just try to get a camel route working using RecipentList. But first a question: What is the difference beween

- Multicast / RecipentList (both without parallel processing)
- multiple "to"
  ?

In my case i want parallel processing for some of my routes. At the moment all use multiple

"to" added within for loop:

```
RouteDefinition someRoute = createSomeRout(fromPart, id); \\ method
for (String pcrfTarget : cepConfig.pcrfCepTargets()) {
    log.info("...to " + pcrfTarget);
    someRoute.to(pcrfTarget + "?mode=" + Mode.insertAddId.name());
}
```

Is there an direct way to use recipientList and just add parallelProcessing at the end?
I also tried to create a simple example but it fails (the only example in books and internet is one using/manipulating header :-(). Here is my example (error):

```
public class Experiments extends CamelTestSupport {
    private static final String MOCK2 = "mock:mock2";
    private static final String MOCK1 = "mock:mock1";
    private static String PCRF_TEST_FILES;

    public Experiments() throws URISyntaxException {
        PCRF_TEST_FILES = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("pcrf-files").toURI().toString();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        MockEndpoint mockIn = getMockEndpoint(MOCK1);
        MockEndpoint mockOut = getMockEndpoint(MOCK2);
        mockIn.expectedMessageCount(5);
        mockOut.expectedMessageCount(5);
        // data in mock are available after this call
        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     *
     * @see org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport#createRouteBuilder()
     */
    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                //from(PCRF_TEST_FILES + "?noop=true").unmarshal().gzip().to(MOCK1).to(MOCK2); //working
                from(PCRF_TEST_FILES + "?noop=true").unmarshal().gzip().recipientList(method(Experiments.class)).parallelProcessing(); //not working
            }
        };
    }

    @RecipientList
    public String[] recipents() {
        return new String[] { MOCK1, MOCK2 };
    }

}
```

I get error:

```
org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[EDR_UPCC244_MPU842_0370_20140428000008.csv.gz]
...
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: expected null, but was:<[B@48d19957>
```

I think for some reason camel tries to use content of files to get recipients?! Could someone provide an example how to dynamically create recipentList but not based on data that comes with exchange but on independent data (in my case given in configuration).

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mixing `@RecipientList` and `recipientList()` is not possible as stated in the [Camel documentation](http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html) (section "Using method call as recipient list"). Thus, just use one or the other.

**1. Use recipientList()**

Remove `@RecipientList` from the method:

```
// No @RecipientList annotation
public String[] recipents() {
    return new String[] { MOCK1, MOCK2 };
}
```

And define the route as follows:

```
from("direct:start")
    .recipientList()
    .method(Experiments.class)  // you may define a method name as well if there is more than one
    .parallelProcessing();
```

Or:

```
from("direct:start")
    .recipientList(method(Experiments.class))  // you may define a method name as well if there is more than one
    .parallelProcessing();
```

**2. Use @RecipientList**

`@RecipientList` is used together with `bean`:

```
from("direct:start")
    .bean(Experiments.class);  // you may define a method name as well if there is more than one
```

To achieve parallel processing, you need to add the `parallelProcessing` attribute to the `@RecipientList` annotation:

```
@RecipientList(parallelProcessing = true)
public String[] recipents() {
    return new String[] { MOCK1, MOCK2 };
}
```